# How to have a ADetail Accessory of TListBoxItem highlight current TListBoxItem

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, tlistbox

In my program, I have dynamically generated TListBoxItems and have used/inserted Ttext Controls onto the ListBoxItems to customize it. My issue is, now That the TText controls sit atop of the Box Items, I lost the ability for a user to select and highlight a Box Item.

IDK if it would be easier to just generate an ADetail Accessory and have that be the control that highlights an item ? Or would it be easier/more beneficial to set the TText.OnClick events to highlight the box items. Either way, I am confused and lost.

I have tried setting the onClick event of the Ttexts to their parent control TListBoxItem, but that does nothing.

I have also tried creating a new procedure and attempted to set the Object Sender.Parent to... well, that's as far as I got.

I am using Delphi Xe4 creating a app for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not check it right now, but try to set the [`HitTest`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Objects.TText.HitTest) property of the [`TText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Objects.TText) to False, so it should not get Click or Tap events.

Comment: Wow. That was really simple! I'm obviously new to Delphi and programming ! Thanks! +1